# For /f is deleting the variable when set with the command used to set the variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wmic

Sorry if I made the title sound a bit confusing. But here's what I'm encountering.

The code:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,3 delims=," %u in ('wmic /node:%CompName% COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME') do set userfound=%u
```

The output:

```
:\windows\system32>set userfound= domain\username
:\windows\system32>set userfound=
```

Picture of the code results:
[Code Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DcaE.png)

The original code:

```
wmic /node:%CompName% COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME
```

It's output:

```
Username
domain\username
```

What I'm trying to do is have a variable only equal the username with out the domain added to it for a batch file. I'll then later have that username saved as a variable that will be saved throughout a number of connected batch files.

I also want to make sure that for /f doesn't loop (even though it is a looping command) doesn't replace my var with nothing.

So I am at a loss at what to code here.

Wanted Result

```
[out put of code]=username
```

Comment: you need to look up the concept of "delayed variable expansion" in the context of cmd.exe

Comment: Use `SET ECHO OFF` then run the FOR command again. When you want the prompt back, use `SET ECHO ON`. You will likely want to put this into a .bat file script. If so, be sure to double the FOR loop % characters.

Comment: This happens in a batch with setting echo off. The result still displays as 

domain\username

Comment: Basically the end result when echoing the variable %Userfound% is ECHO is off.

Comment: @MikeNakis, delayed expansion is not the solution here as no variable is read in the `for /F` loop; the problem is the Unicode output of `wmic` and the poor conversion to ANSI text by `for /F`; [npocmaka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43876911) provides the perfect solution for this, using two nested `for /F` loops to fet rid of conversion artefacts...

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %u in ('wmic /node:%CompName% COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME^|find "\"') do set userfound=%~nxu
```

The `tokens` is not required, nor is the `skip`. Removing he delimiters (empty delimiter set) delivers the entire line to `%u`.

The caret before the pipe escapes it to signify that it's part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`.

The `find` command simply filters out the line containing the `\`.

the `~nx` before the `u` means that, treating the name in `%u` as a filename, select just the name and extension (ie, that part after the final `\`)

Comment: BTW - the reason that the data appears to disappear is that `wmic`'s output is not standard windows CRLF-terminated. It includes CR alone which `cmd` interprets a a new (empty) line. (look at the actual bytes when redirected to a file using a hex-editor or hex-viewer)

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I've been playing around with the for command for a while to try to get this result. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,3 delims=," %%u in (
    'wmic  COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME'
) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%u") do set userfound=%%#
) 

echo %userfound%
```